# Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Employee'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to generate drivers from the command ..

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name EmployeeController -m Employee  -dc EmsContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

```
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Employee'
A file matching the name MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml was not found within any of the folders: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

It is the last step according to a documentation, I am starting with this Framework but I cannot get out of this status. I am using Ubuntu and all through the terminal. If someone can give me an indication of how to solve it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

As @ericc-eacs Answer, you need to copy the template and in case you just following the getting started tutorial(.net core), make sure to remove the folder to the template of identity as when you build it will give some errors. You just need the templates to create the views and controllers.

[image: Template folder]

Comment: Copy it form here /home/USER/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc/5.0.0/Templates to your project folder

Answer (score 0):

What version of the dotnetcore SDK are you using?
`dotnet --version`

You may need to install a different version of the aspnet-codegenerator.
Some helpful commands:

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.0
dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the version I am using is dotnet 3.1.302. Run the commands it gave me and the dotnet tool is updated to version 3.1.4. Even if I'm still in the same situation :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for UBUNTU valid for net core 3.0, 3.1, and 5.0.
27/NOVEMBER/2020

ControllerGenerator contains de file MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml

**You just copy the Templates folders** Template/ControllerGenerator and Template/ViewGenerator to own project.

Look the version in this example is 5.0.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUVS5.png)
This is the path of the missing files: /home/$USER/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc/5.0.0/Templates

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this issue exists at least since november and have not found solution for it. Using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Rider EAP 2020.3. C# 9, dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator version '5.0.1', dotnet 5.0.102.

When running the utility to build crud pages for Razor Pages web app:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m GpsSession -dc ApplicationDbContext -udl -outDir Pages/GpsSessions --referenceScriptLibraries
```

The following output is given:

```
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'GpsSession'
A file matching the name Create.cshtml was not found within any of the folders: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

When I run the same command on same repository in Win10 then everything works perfectly, crud pages are generated without any errors.

Comment: Please do not post confirmation of the question's issue as an answer.